# Directional derivatives of a differentiable function where the function takes direction vector as a parameter

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

By the first order approximation, the directional derivative of a differentiable function $f:R^d \rightarrow R$ at point $x \in R^d$ can be expressed as

\begin{equation}
\label{equation:eq1}
\nabla_{v}{f(x)} = \nabla{f(x)} \cdot v
\end{equation}

where $v \in R^d$ is a directional vector.

However, what if the function takes a directional vector as a parameter?

\begin{equation}
\label{equation:eq2}
\nabla_{v}{f(x,v)}
\end{equation}

where $f$ is a KL-divergence function(i.e.$~f(x,v)$ = $KL$[ $p$$($$\cdot$$|$$x$$)$ $||$ $p$$($$\cdot$$|$$x+v$$)$]).

In this problem setting, can I approximate the given directional derivative similar to the first-order approximation of a directional derivative where it only has to get gradients for the current input $x$?